# fill DropdownList from xml using ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have on one page a dropdownlist which I would like to use AJAX in order to populate it from a XML file. Is there a way to tell AJAX to run only certain asp.net method without using WebServices?
 Any other solution is welcome but the only restriction is that it would be made on the server side (and not with js for example)?

thanks!

Comment: Could you post some sample code please? Are you using the AJAX Control Toolkit or some other method to hook up the SELECT box to AJAX?

Comment: No. I just have a DropDownList, and an XML file on the server, and I need to have AJAX to call a function on the server that does some manipulations on the XML and gets a list of item i would like to bund to the dropdownlist. Is that even possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "without using WebServices". If you're using Ajax, you *are* using a webservice, which is not different from any other normal http request.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through a variety of means - one approach is to use jQuery on the client-side to generate the AJAX request like so (binding to the page ready here, but it could be bound to the SELECT change event):

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $.get('/target-url.aspx?someparam=somevalue', function(data) {
    // process the returned data - dependant on the format - assuming JSON here.
    var items = data['items'];

    // may wish to clear the contents of the SELECT box.

    // spin through and add OPTION elements
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      $('#selectid').append('<option>'+items[i]+'</option>');
    }
  }
}
```

Where selectid is the ID of the dropdownlist element (use the ClientId if in ASP.NET).

Then you need to write some code in ASP.NET to respond to the AJAX request with your desired logic.

Some useful links:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

See here for an example of using jQuery and ASP.NET with JSON:

http://encosia.com/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/

Comment: Thanks, but I am missing something: In the ASP.NET code - where should I put my logic (in which method?)?, how can I return the 'items' JSON?

Comment: I just added another link with an example in which should help you